# Can't exit iPython shell in VSCode with program input statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run a script in an interactive Python shell in VSCode that has an input statement, I can't figure out how to exit while the code is running. I've tried CTRL + C and ESC but that doesn't work. The problem seems to be that the input statement bar covers the Jupyter break button (see below). Am I missing something obvious here?

[image]

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I reproduced your question.

Using Jupyter in vscode, the input box does cover the top button.

I successfully exit the input box with ESC, but the premise is that the mouse cursor is not in terminal.(python:3.8.3; VSCode: x64-1.47.0)

If it still doesn't work,hopefully you could provide more relevant information.